# AngularJS - access factory service from the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm trying to access `factory` service within `controller` to obtain correct data.

Related controller code looks like:

```
myApp.controller('RegistrationController', ['$scope','$routeParams','$rootScope','$location','$filter','$mdDialog','checkAttendee', function($scope, $routeParams, $rootScope, $location, $filter, $mdDialog,checkAttendee){

...

    $scope.addAttendee = function(ev) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: AddDialogCntrl,
            templateUrl: 'views/regForm.tmpl.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose:true,
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen, // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
            locals: {parent: $scope}
        })
        .then(
            function(response){
                if(angular.isDefined(response)){
                    attendees.push(response);
                    checkAttendee.getAttendeeInfo(response);                     
                }
            },
            function(){
                //no changes
            }
        )
        .catch(
            function(error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error);
            }
        ) 
    };
```

and `factory` service code

```
myApp.factory('checkAttendee', ['$http', function($http) {

    this.getAttendeeInfo = function(req) {

        return $http.get("/check/attendee/",  {params:{"firstName":req.firstName, "lastName":req.lastName, "email": req.email, "eventID": req.eventID}})
            .then(function(response) {
                var data = response.data;
                var status = response.status;
                var statusText = response.statusText;
                var headers = response.headers;
                var config = response.config;

                console.log('Data: ' + data);  
                console.log('Status: ' + status);

                return data;    
            })
            .catch(function(response) {
                console.log('something worng');
            });
    }
}]);
```

but that combination gives me an error `Provider 'checkAttendee' must return a value from $get factory method.` when there is a return value.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1

When we work with factories the structure should be:

```
myApp.factory('checkAttendee', ['$http', function($http) {

var factory = {

       getAttendeeInfo : function () {                
            return $http.get(/**/).then(function(response) {
                  // ..
                   return data;   
            }                         
        }
   }       
    return factory;
}]);
```

<kbd>[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/dzmn8f27/)</kbd>

#### Option 2

you can change `factory` to `service` and everything should work. A.e.:

```
myApp.service('checkAttendee', ['$http', function($http) {

    this.getAttendeeInfo = function(req) {

        return $http.get("/check/attendee/",  {params:{"firstName":req.firstName, "lastName":req.lastName, "email": req.email, "eventID": req.eventID}})
            .then(function(response) {
                var data = response.data;
                var status = response.status;
                var statusText = response.statusText;
                var headers = response.headers;
                var config = response.config;

                console.log('Data: ' + data);  
                console.log('Status: ' + status);

                return data;    
            })
            .catch(function(response) {
                console.log('something worng');
                throw response;
            });
    }
}]);
```

<kbd>[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/vL44qdoc/)</kbd>

---

Keep in mind that `service` extends the `factory`

Comment: It is important to re-throw errors from` .catch` handlers. Otherwise rejected promises will be converted to fulfilled promises.

Comment: Somehow I'm getting `{"$$state":{"status":0}}` for the `return factory` but then `Status: 200` for the `console.log('Status: ' + status);` Any thoughts?

Comment: @JackTheKnife it looks like Promise output. Resolve it in modal: `checkAttendee.getAttendeeInfo(response).then() .....`

Comment: @MaximShoustin Moved some pieces code around and got it to work. Thanks!